# How do you send Mass Emails to a list larger than 500?

Tags: email, massemailmessage, mass-email

We currently do not have a third party vendor Mass Email plug-in, so we are working towards using the out of the box functionality for Mass Emailing from Salesforce; we have the Enterprise edition, so our limit is 500 recipients max per email message, 1000 recipients max/day. If I have a list of 900 Contacts that I want to send a Mass Email to, I can go through the Mass Email process, create my Contact List View for the email, and then proceed to send the message, which would go to the first 500 Contacts on my list. Once that is sent, how do I send the other 400 Contacts the email message? If I go through the Mass Email process again, and select the same List View I used the first time, will Salesforce know which Contacts have already received that communication? Has anyone else run up against this issue?

Comment: I think the quick fix here is to create two separate lists, one for the first batch of 500 and then the other for the batch of 400. In the meantime, I'm looking into this further. I suspect though that if a contact is in the first batch of 500 and the second batch of 400, that he/she will receive 2 emails.

Comment: So I looked into this more. You shouldn't be able to create a list longer than the max limit of recipients per mass mail. So if you're limit is 500 recipients per mass mail, your list won't be longer than 500. Is that what you experience too? Or can you create a mass mail list > 500?